# Receiving ORA-00001 error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am receiving an ORA-00001 error when I try to run my database. Fairly new to sql so getting myself confused aswell as over thinking this. Would someone be able to help please?

Code:

```
    drop table shoppingid cascade constraints

    create table Shoppingid(
    shoppingid varchar2(20) 
        constraint  pk_shoppingid primary key,
    shoppinginfo varchar2(80)
        constraint nn_shoppinginfo not null,
    shoppingvalue number(2)
        constraint nn_shoppingvalue not null        
    )

    INSERT INTO shoppingid VALUES('SI696', 'None', 0)
```

Comment: You probably are running that INSERT twice. How exactly are you running that script? And with which tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no statement terminators (semi-colon or a forward slash) in your message. However, if you use both of them, you will get such an error. For example:

```
SQL> create table Shoppingid(
  2      shoppingid varchar2(20)
  3          constraint  pk_shoppingid primary key,
  4      shoppinginfo varchar2(80)
  5          constraint nn_shoppinginfo not null,
  6      shoppingvalue number(2)
  7          constraint nn_shoppingvalue not null
  8      )
  9  ;

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO shoppingid VALUES('SI696', 'None', 0);

1 row created.

SQL> /                                                 ---->>> this!
INSERT INTO shoppingid VALUES('SI696', 'None', 0)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.PK_SHOPPINGID) violated


SQL>
```

A forward slash will "repeat" the last command. Therefore, remove it in such a case.

Note that it is required, though, if you use PL/SQL blocks (anonymous or named).